# How to respond to well-known sockpuppeters

Tags: discussion, blacklist

Frequent sockpuppeter/spammer Wolfgang Muckenheim is [back](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417984/why-has-my-answer-been-deleted), and across multiple SE sites ([philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/89909/18947), [mse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/produce-an-explicit-bijection-between-rationals-and-naturals/4401107#4401107)). This leads me to ask:

> Is there anything specific we should do in a situation like this, besides simply flagging the offending user's posts?

I know for example that there are some [blacklisted phrases](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/banned-content-in-comments-flags-questions) in the SE network; could we similarly blacklist Wolfgang's site (which he always links to)?

(I'd also like to take the opportunity to request that folks not feed this particular troll.)

Comment: As [mentioned elsewhere](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2022/3/13), the tag ([meta-tag:blacklist]) would probably be a reasonable fit for this question - after all, one of the suggestions is to blacklist a specific site.
(I also thought about ([meta-tag:specific-user]) and ([meta-tag:spam]). But these two tags probably do not fit the question that well.)

Comment: I also wanted to check whether the site appears in some legitimate posts. Searching [for the posts containing the link](https://stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2Amueckenh%2A%22) (and haven't been deleted), I'd say that: 
The two posts on [math.se] ([3768948](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3768948) and [4185694](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4185694)) seems to be genuine posts, so does  [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/315502#343696) on [stats.se].

Comment: However, [all posts on Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22%2Amueckenh%2A%22) come from the same user - who is now suspended.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I mostly understand the suspension, but the user’s answers are informative, so what is wrong with them?

Comment: @TymaGaidash If you mean the posts on [philosophy.se], I am not competent enough to say whether or not they were useful. (I now almost nothing about philosophy.) I have mentioned this [in the chatroom of that site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/538/2022/3/17) - maybe somebody might notice that and respond there.)

Comment: @TymaGaidash: Why are they informative??

Comment: @TymaGaidash There was some response from a moderator of the Philosophy site: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/538/2022/3/23

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Flag, flag, flag. Flag as rude, flag as spam, downvote, flag for moderator attention so we'll see the account and nuke it.

Flag.

Oh, and **do not** engage. Well-known trolls tend to be attention seekers. Without attention, and with their content quickly removed and their accounts blacklisted, we increase the chance of them not coming back, at least not as often.